# Ajax Request status

Tags: php, ajax

Am I missing something.

I am making a simple AJAX request to a .php page with a simple echo "hello" statement in it, When I host this page on my localhost then I get the response back fine.
But when I upload this page on a remote server I don't get the status 200 on the request, I have tested it by opening the page in the browser it works fine even there. I am stumped!

Comment: Can you post your javascript code?

Comment: Remember that you can only use AJAX to request pages on the same domain.

Comment: Oh I see,  I can't make an ajax request across servers is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Funny but I have faced the same thing tonight. 
Be sure to omit  the "www." from the Ajax call URL. This helped me. 
When I had this inside my URL I used to get status 302 which is a "redirect" status. 
Another thing u might want to test is put 127.0.0.1 in your address instead of localhost and see if it's working.